# Find more solutions by using Minimize function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'd like to  find minmum value in  x^2*y under equation constraint x^2 + y^2 == 1
Hence, I use following code:

```
Minimize[{x^2*y, x^2 + y^2 == 1}, {x, y}]
```

I got

$$\left\{-\frac{2}{3 \sqrt{3}},\left\{x\to -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}},y\to -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right\}\right\}$$

For the method of Lagrange multipliers,

```
s1 = Solve[{2 x*y + 2 l*x == 0, x^2 + 2 l*y == 0, 
    x^2 + y^2 - 1 == 0}, {x, y, l}];
ReplaceAll[x^2 y, #] & /@ s1
s1[[3]]
s1[[5]]
```

$$\left\{0,0,-\frac{2}{3 \sqrt{3}},\frac{2}{3 \sqrt{3}},-\frac{2}{3 \sqrt{3}},\frac{2}{3 \sqrt{3}}\right\}$$
$$\left\{x\to -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}},y\to -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},l\to \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right\}$$

$$\left\{x\to \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}},y\to -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},l\to \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right\}$$

I can get two solutions. If I use Minimize function, How to get more Minimum solution?

Comment: Note you can convert to polar using $x = \cos(\theta), y = \sin(\theta)$ and $r=1$, so you could also do this: `FullSimplify[ToRadicals[Quiet[Minimize[{Cos[θ]^2 Sin[θ], 0 <= θ <= 2 π}, θ]]]]]]]`

Comment: Since `x` only appears as `x^2` use `Minimize[{x^2*y, x^2 + y^2 == 1, #}, {x, y}] & /@ {x >= 0,  x < 0}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] = x^2*y;
g[x_, y_] = x^2 + y^2 - 1;
```

I take up Bob Hanlon's thoughts here:

```
min = Minimize[{f[x, y], g[x, y] == 0, #}, {x, y}] & /@ {x >= 0, x < 0}
```

[image]

what kind of points are they?

```
hessian = D[f[x, y], {{x, y}, 2}] /. {min[[1, 2]], min[[2, 2]]};
Det /@ hessian
```

[image]

strictly, these are saddle points

Answer (score 2):

First, let's plot the surface $z=x^2y$ and a circle projected onto the surface. This should help you see that there are only two minima - the two warped down parts of the circle nearest to us in the plot:

```
Show[
 Plot3D[x^2 y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1.3, 1.3}, PlotTheme -> "Classic", 
  BoxRatios -> 1],
 ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], Cos[t]^2 Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Green, Thick}]
 ]
```

[image: surface plot with circle]

If we use the transformation $x = \cos(\theta), y = \sin(\theta)$ and $r=1$, we can minimize $x^2 y = \cos(\theta)^2\sin(\theta)$ to find a family of solutions:

```
solutions = 
 FullSimplify[ToRadicals[
   Quiet[Minimize[{Cos[θ]^2 Sin[θ], 12 π <= θ}, θ]]]]
```

You can see this minimium attained along a line at $y = \frac{-2}{3\sqrt{3}}$:

[image: plot with minima]

Then get the values of $\theta$ with:

```
solt = t /. Solve[Cos[t]^2 Sin[t] == -2/(3 Sqrt[3]), t, Reals];
```

Though it should be obvious the wave repeats cycles $2\pi$ apart without needing to solve it.

We have $\hat{\theta}_1=2 \pi  k-\arctan\left(1/\sqrt{2}\right)$ and $\hat{\theta}_2=2 \pi  k-\pi+\arctan\left(1/\sqrt{2}\right)$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

These correspond to the pairs of points in each cycle of the wave above. If you plug these back into $x=\cos(\hat{\theta}_i),y=\sin(\hat{\theta}_i)$ there are only two possible solutions - and you've already given them.

Comment: I use solt = t /. Solve[Cos[t]^2 Sin[t] == -2/(3 Sqrt[3]), t, Reals]; I got  ConditionalExpression[2 ArcTan[
Root[1 - 10 #^2 + #^4& , 1, 0]] + 
  2 \[Pi] ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]], 
 ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]] \[Element] Integers]
and
ConditionalExpression[2 ArcTan[
Root[1 - 10 #^2 + #^4& , 2, 0]] + 
  2 \[Pi] ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]], 
 ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]] \[Element] Integers].

Comment: That's weird but I can confirm. If you remove `Reals` you get answers with `Arctan[1/Sqrt[2]]` but note that `-2 ArcTan[Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[6]]] == -\[Pi] + ArcTan[1/Sqrt[2]]` anyway so you can still proceed to solve the problem. `FullSimplify[Cos[-2 ArcTan[Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[6]]]]]` gives `-Sqrt[2/3]` for instance.